# Is there a better way than this loopin logic?

Tags: python, loops, stack, logic

I have an array with id name and marks.

and i want to calculate total mark and execute an operation when the next student comes in.

I am using the bellow code but i need to call the method finally after completing the operation.

Is there a better way than this without calling the method after the loop.

```
student_id_name_marks = [
    (1,"John",23),
    (2,"Paul",30),
    (2,"Paul",32),
    (2,"Paul",40),
    (3,"Doe",43),
    (3,"Doe",42),
    (4,"Jerry",45)
]


current_user_id = None
total_marks = None
for marks in student_id_name_marks:
    if current_user_id == marks[0]:
        total_marks += marks[2]
    else:
        if total_marks:
            calculate_average(total_marks)
        total_marks = marks[2]
        current_user_id = marks[0]

if total_marks:
            calculate_average(total_marks)
```

Comment: Your problem sounds like a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict), with keys the student names and values a list of grades obtained by the student, would be a more natural representation of the data. Do you have a choice of the input format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would store them in a dictionary

```
from collections import defaultdict
marks = defaultdict(list)
for id, name, mark in student_id_name_marks:
     marks[name].append(mark)  # could use the id instead of name as key
```

then you can just calculate the average for each person afterwards, which is still the best way to do it.

```
for key, val in marks.items():
     calculate_average(val) # key will be the persons name if you need it
```

Alternatively, consider making a `Person` class, that contains the id, name and list of marks. then keep a list of those objects and work on the person object as you need

```
class Person:
     def __init__(self, id, name):
          self.id = id
          self.name = name
          self.marks = []
    def add_mark(mark):
          self.marks.append(mark)
    def average_mark():
          return sum(self.marks) / len(self.marks)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could transform your list into a pandas dataframe for easier and faster computations :

```
student_id_name_marks = [
    (1,"John",23),
    (2,"Paul",30),
    (2,"Paul",32),
    (2,"Paul",40),
    (3,"Doe",43),
    (3,"Doe",42),
    (4,"Jerry",45)
]

df= pd.DataFrame(student_id_name_marks)
df.columns = ['id', 'Name', 'Mark']

   id   Name  Mark
0   1   John    23
1   2   Paul    30
2   2   Paul    32
3   2   Paul    40
4   3    Doe    43
5   3    Doe    42
6   4  Jerry    45

# We groupby students to get each student's average mark
students_mean = df.groupby('id')['Mark'].mean()

# We compute the average mark
students_mean .mean()
```

---

Output :

```
36.125
```

Answer (score 0):

You could append an entry to the list and ignore it:

```
student_id_name_marks = [    
    (1,"John",23),    
    (2,"Paul",30),    
    (2,"Paul",32),    
    (2,"Paul",40),    
    (3,"Doe",43),    
    (3,"Doe",42),    
    (4,"Jerry",45),    
    (-1,"EOF",0),     
]    

current_user_id = None    
total_marks = None        
for marks in student_id_name_marks:    
    if current_user_id == marks[0]:    
        total_marks += marks[2]        
    else:                              
        if total_marks:                
            print(current_user_id, total_marks)    
        total_marks = marks[2]    
        current_user_id = marks[0]
```

Produces:

```
1 23
2 102
3 85
4 45
```